# codeIgniter Datamapper Get Only Query Results

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-datamapper

I want to save results to cache but datamapper result objects is huge array.

I want to get **only my query results** without other data that referenced codeigniter data (models/configs/languages/etc..)

How can do this?

I searched on SO, internet and manual page (http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/) but i couldnt find anything..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to access the core information about your records, try using the array extension here: http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/extensions/array.html

This allows you to run something like:

```
$objects-> all_to_array();
```

... which returns an array of objects, with all properties, but without the models/configs/languages &c. that you mention.

Answer (score 0):

I want to addition some tips on @sevenpointsix answer

If you are using `include_related`, you have to specify columns like following (`relation_column`):

```
$fields = array('id', 'title', 'user_firstname', 'user_lastname', 'category_name');
$posts->get()->all_to_array($fields);
```